# Excel conditional formatting doesn't match formula TRUE/FALSE output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This should theoretically be a simple use-case: many people in my organization have a need to regularly figure out interest earned by specific deposits or investment contributions. My sheet expedites this by allowing users to input the date and amount of each item into a table, after which it handles all the necessary calculation. The table's length is, necessarily, variable.

Because not all of my users are technically literate, I want this table to *look* like a table, but I only want to format rows with actual data. The automatic table formatting will not work for this use<sup>1</sup>, so I want to apply conditional formatting to each even row containing data. I wrote a formula that should work, just checking whether the row is even and whether the "amount" column isn't blank:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))),ISEVEN(ROW()))
```

I've placed this formula in a column to the right of the table, and as expected it displays TRUE for every even row with data in the "amount" column, and FALSE for everything else. Trouble is, when I go to apply conditional formatting to the table area, it continues to apply formatting even when `NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))` evaluates to FALSE, which *should* make the entire `AND()` FALSE.

So the question is: **Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?** I'm stumped, since the formula outputs correctly when used on the sheet, and I can't directly evaluate it from the conditional formatting page.

<sup>1</sup> Automatic table formatting *should* work for this, but my users have found ways to break it without knowing they've done so, so I need something I have more control over.

Comment: `=AND(INDEX($B:$B,ROW())<>"",ISEVEN(ROW()))`

Comment: I agree with Scott, stay away from INDIRECT and instead of ISBLANK just compare against ""

Comment: Scott, that works perfectly. Would you care to explain why it behaves differently (and is a better method) and submit that as an answer so I can give you credit? Thank you!

Comment: It is better because it is not volatile.  INDIRECT is volatile.  As to why mine works and yours does not I do not know, hence why I did not answer.

Comment: Going for bigger tables, it may be faster to directly use something like `=LEN($B1)*ISEVEN(ROW())` (still the 1 needs to fit the first row used for your formatting - if starting at row 2, then $B2...)

Comment: It seems there is a problem in the logic here (Excel itself). Using `=NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))` works fine. Also `=NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))*1` does. But `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))),1)` does fail (is always true). But it IS a good question why exactly this combination does not work. It seems that in conditional formatting `NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))` will always be true inside `OR` and `AND` (the used column doesn't matter for this).